# missing chunk names in knitr tangled R code

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, noweb

When using `Stangle` on a `Sweave` document, the output includes a comment that gives the chunk name.  This is incredibly useful in a teaching setting to orient students in the code as they cut-and-paste.  However, when I use `knitr` to generate the `.R` code from a `.Rnw`, the chunk names are not included (at least that I can see):

```
knit('example.Rnw',tangle=TRUE)
```

I could run `Stangle` on a document written for `knitr` except that there are incompatibilities in chunk arguments that preclude running `Stangle` without errors.

**Is there a way to force `knitr` to produce comments in tangled `R` code that include chunk names (and/or numbers) like native `Stangle`?**

Comment: I was really surprised -- I thought this would work, but I guess ?? it only works for tangling Rmarkdown ??  +1 ...

Comment: This appears to work with `purl()`.  Not sure yet what the difference is between `purl()` and `knit(., tangle=TRUE)` ...

Comment: It depends on the `documentation` level. See `?purl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @kohske (I had just about figured this out for myself ...)

`purl()` has a `documentation` argument, which is set to 1 by default (1=add chunk headers to code; 0 does nothing, 2 adds chunk headers as roxygen comments).  If you want to stick to `knit(.,tangle=TRUE)` you just need to `opts_knit$set(documentation=1)` before tangling.